# Firing different sensor threads sends data to same socket?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

The closest question to my problem so far has been:
[How to handle same socket in different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523916/how-to-handle-same-socket-in-different-threads)

But it didn't help me in my pursuit. I have several sensor threads which are fired at random intervals to a client socket which in turn sends that data to the server socket.

But I get the issue when the sensor threads are fired at the same time then the data of those threads get mixed up. I don't want that behavior to happen, I want all those threads to be fired distinctly without being fired at the same point at any time. Please give me methods in which achieve this. I can't seem to think of a good solution on my own.

P.S. I am emulating a test branch environment where the sensors are fired in different threads (as if attached to client socket) to send data to this client on different topics than to the broker. When I use to sleep on the sensor threads and the data mixup still occurs at some point later on.

Comment: Please  do correct me if i didnt  present my question in an organised way

Comment: Please read the How to ask Good Questions doc http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also it's not clear why this is tagged with MQTT, a MQTT client will multiplex multiple threads to a single outgoing connection to a broker

Comment: actually i  am  emulating  MQTT client  as   separate threads  and sensors  attached to it also as different detached  threads so i tagged it  as mqtt

Comment: this is  a test  bench  environment  where  all these mqtt clients are emulated as  different threads having  sensors  attached to it  also  as  separatethreads   firing  independently  to  that particular  mqtt client

Comment: Then each thread should use its own socket as that is what a real client would do

Comment: i am putting  each  client  in separate threads and  sensors attached  to the client  too as  detached threads.They are  firing  in a  random  fashion so when  different sensors publish  at  the  same  client simultneously  the  publish   data  gets  mixed up.I  want  all  the  publish packets  to be  fired  distinctly  not  getting  mixed  up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually it should be pretty easy, have your separate threads push your data to an exclusive-access container (like an array or a queue), then a separate thread forward the data from your container to the socket.

This way you have only one thread dealing with socket communication at a time.

Comment: yes  but  how  do i avoid  the clash  if  it  occurs  when  both  threads  are  fired  at  the same time   to  the  same  client  socket  to  the  same  server socket

Comment: actually  to be  frank  am  using  paho  client  to  publish or  subscribe to message so  i  canrt  really  figure  out  how  to tweak  that  behaviour

Comment: I don't know what you mean, in the scenario I presented data would be sent to the server in perfectly sequential order from a single thread.

Comment: ok what  i mean  is  i am firing sensors in different  threads  to mqtt client  which  is  run in  separate thread  so a scenario may come  that  2 or many sensor  threads  may publish  data  sumultaneously  thus  causing  mixing in data .How do  i  avoid  that

Comment: By serializing it to an exclusive-access container, as I said. Is the problem here that you don't know how to use a mutex? Or adding to an array? What *exactly* is your difficulty implementing this?

Comment: thats  exactly  the  point  i  really  cant  follow  exactly  what u intend  to  say

Comment: i  have  used  mutex  but  it  really  doesnt  help  much

Comment: A mutex helps run portions of (otherwise parallel) threads in sequence. That's exactly what you want.

Comment: thanx a  lot i  have  now  put  a mutex  at  the  point where the actual  data is published  from  paho  now i am testing for its accuracy

Comment: still  i am getting  data mixup on the  server  side  once in  a  while

Comment: Post a question about it and show your code, I can only guess at what you did wrong.

Comment: actually the code involoves several file i can send you the files via email if its convenient for u thats y i cant specifically post code in this forum

Comment: after performing some trial and errors the error i think is not coming from my code i may be wrong sometimes packet identier bit is wrapped up in the packet format and sometimes not so the packet format byte lenght decreases by 2

Comment: its been resolved now i did some mistake on my server code and it thus it was giving data mixup